# Tablix header repetition on each page in rdlc

Tags: asp.net, reporting-services, rdlc

I am building report in `rdlc` report writer in `vs2010 sp1` I want to repeat the header of `tablix`  on each page but this repetition is viewed in preview but not in exported `pdf`.

I have tried tablix properties by going in advance properties and set

```
(RepeatOnNewPage->true) 
(FixedData->true)
(keepWithGroup->after)
```

but not getting results.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

did you tried with checking repeat header on each page?